# Extract text from div class with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am using python along with scrapy. I want to extract the text from the div tag which is inside a div class. For example:

```
 <div class="ld-header">
    <h1>2013 Gulfstream G650ER  for Sale</h1>
    <div id="header-price">Price - $46,500,000</div>
</div>
```

I've extracted text from h1 tag

```
result.xpath('//div[@class="ld-header"]/h1/text()').extract()
```

but I can't extract Price. I've tried

```
'price': result.xpath('//div[@class="ld-header"]/div[@id="header-price"]/text()').extract()
```

Comment: Your XPath is correct, but the value itself might be dynamic (probably received from XHR).

Answer (score 1):

As you have an id, you do not need to use the complete path to the element. Ids are unique per Webpage:

This Xpath:

```
//div[@id="header-price"]/text()
```

used on the give XML will return:

```
'Price - $46,500,000'
```

For debugging Xpath and CSS Selectors, I always find it helpful to use an online checker (just use Google to find some suggestions).

Comment: I've just try, but anyway - i have not received Price - just empty string

Comment: Could you provide the acutal lines of code? The Xpath should work, I have tested it locally.

Comment: { import scrapy

class PlaneSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'planespider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.globalair.com/aircraft-for-sale/ListingDetail/Gulfstream-G650ER?AdId=85963']

    def parse(self, response):
        for result in response.css('.content'):
            yield {
                'name': result.xpath('//div[@class="ld-header"]/h1/text()').extract(),
                'price': result.xpath('//div[@class="ld-header"]/div[@id="header-price"].text()')
                # 'price': result.xpath('//div[@class="ld-header"]/div/text()')
            }
}

Comment: Looks like you are missing the Scrapy-specific .extract() in your call. `price = result.xpath('//div[@id="header-price"]/text()).extract()`

Comment: I've tried also in a such manner, bit anyway result is empty string. Looks like that Andersson is right and it's XHR question. Anyway - thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try This one and you tell me :)

```
price = [x.replace('Price - ', '').replace('$', '') for x in result.xpath('//div[@class="ld-header"]/h1/text()').extract()]
```

This is a 'for' loop inside all the items in the extraction where you replace all the info you don't need with the 'replace()' method.